# Why is a job artifact not being added in the pipeline?

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci, pipeline

UPDATE: added when:always under artifacts fixed the issue, since the unit tests were failing, so the coverage folder was not created as an artifact

---

When unit tests are run, a coverage folder is created. I want to save that coverage folder as an artifact in the pipeline so that sonarqube can access the reports in that folder to give an accurate coverage report. When I push up any code, I'm not seeing the coverage folder being saved as an artifact after the unit tests are run in the pre-build stage, so it is not being passed along to sonarqube in the build stage.

This is the yml file:

```
stages:
  - Pre-Build
  - Build
  - etc.

Unit Tests:
  stage: Pre-Build
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage
    when: always

SonarQube:
  stage: Build
  needs: ['Unit Tests']
  except:
    refs:
      - tags
```

Answer (score 1):

try add slash in dir-path

```
    Unit Tests:
  stage: Pre-Build
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/
    when: always
```